# I'm having a problem getting ubuntu installed

Tags: boot, usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.3 on my Lenovo 11e laptop with Windows 10 Pro, but my laptop won't boot from the thumb drive. I have tried the suggestion to click the <kbd>F12</kbd> key when the computer is booting and a menu comes up with the thumb drive showing, which I highlight and click enter, but nothing happens except the menu fades away and then comes back quickly. I have also went into the setup menu and tried making all kinds of changes that I thought might help, but none did, even resetting to all defaults. On one of the changes I made in setup, I could not tell you which one at this point, but I got a message saying that there was not an operating system found on the thumb drive. I also tried using a different thumb drive. I have plenty of storage on my hard drive. Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: How did you set up the thumb drive?  Did you hashcheck the downloaded iso before you used it?

Comment: I don't know what hashcheck means, but I formatted a thumb drive and downloaded ubuntu to my laptop and then copied the file to the thumb drive and on another try I formatted a different thumb drive and downloaded ubuntu directly to the thumb drive.  I did open the file to see that it had it had ubuntu files in it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Did you md5sum check the downloaded iso?
   See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM
   Check the number against the listing in the link for your release listed at
   http://releases.ubuntu.com under the MD5SUMS link.
   For other releases' hashes, like lubuntu, see:
   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes
2. Create the USB install media with a tool like unetbootin or rufus.  Don't just copy files to the USB.
   See   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation
3. Did you select the media check before trying to install?
   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck
4. Did you ever do a "memory check" (perhaps another live-media menu choice) on your PC?
   Doing the above can save you a lot of time struggling with a bad install media or hardware problems.

Comment: Only adding this comment for clarification.  Follow the instructions and info links from @ubfan1 because you will then put an image on the USB stick. A .iso file is a disk image and must be copied to the USB as that image or the booting capabilities will not exist. Simply copying the ISO file to the stick does not actually create the image on the USB stick, but using the programs suggested by ubfan1 will do that very thing.